# \end{align*} error

Tags: amsmath, siunitx

My LaTeX editor always shows me an error using `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`

Where is my mistake?

Notice: These are just random numbers in my equation.

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
w = \frac{\SI{0.1}{\frac{\mole}{\litre}} \cdot \SI{0.1}{\litre} \cdot \SI{0.1}{\frac{\gram}{\mole}}}{\SI{0.1}{\gram}}\cdot 100 \approx 0.1\%
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What LaTeX editor are you using?

Comment: I am using TeXShop

Comment: I use TeXshop, versions 4.64 and 4.62, and I don't see any kind of error indication. Please edit your query and post a screenshot.

Comment: I am using TeXShop 4.64 - there is a screenshot in my edit.

Comment: There's no error running against my LaTeX.  Perhaps you have something out of date?

Comment: TeX Live Utility is telling me, that there are no updates available @DonHosek

Comment: Please provide the log file from your compilation of this exact example, not an image from your editor, the actual log from disk

Comment: `\frac{\mole}{\litre}` looks a bit unusual. Why don't you use `\mole\per\litre` in combination with `\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}`. If you later on decide that you would prefer a different style, you can easily change it by chosing a different `per-mode` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using version 3.0.7 of the `siunitx` package, I can reproduce the error message you get.

As mentioned before, `\frac{\mole}{\litre}` inside the units part of `\SI` looks somewhat unusual, so I'd start by replacing it with `\mole\per\litre`. In combination with `\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}` you should get the expected output.

If you use `siunitx` version 3., as well, replace `\SI` with `\qty`. According the section "5 Upgrading from version 2", commands like `\SI` stay available, but it it recommended to use `\qty` in new documents, instead.

Since there are currently no alignment poinst (`&`) given in your `align*` environment, a simple `\[`...`\]` would also work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
w = \frac{\qty{0.1}{\mole\per\litre} \cdot \qty{0.1}{\litre} \cdot \qty{0.1}{\gram\per\mole}}{\qty{0.1}{\gram}}\cdot 100 \approx 0.1\%
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that `\frac{\mole}{\litre}` worked in previous releases just by chance.

Comment: Thank you very much @leandriis

Comment: Actually, since `align*` is designed for multiline displays, `\[ ... \]` is really better.